# How automatically track schema changes?

Tags: git, database-schema, database-migration

I work on a team and use Git for version controlling. Each team member has his own local mysql server.  When I alter a table on  db I need its query to be propagated among all db instances. I there any way or tool to track schema changes?

Comment: There are 2 tools that are often used. Liquibase and Flyway. For a discussion about the pros and cons see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418814/db-migration-tool-liquibase-or-flyway

Answer (score 1):

We use Flyway to maintain the DB Schema... you can find more details at their website http://flywaydb.org/

The concept in summary is:

1. You maintain all the changes in SQL scripts, with a naming
   convention V< incrementingCounter >__< any name >.sql
2. You hook Flyway on your app start up, it automatically migrates your DB to the latest
   version

Is this something you are looking for?